# Forcing Opengl 2.0 and above in c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am a student learning c++ and opengl for 5 months now and we have touched some advanced topics over the course of time starting from basic opengl like glBegin/glEnd to VA to VBO to shaders etc. Our professor has made us build up our graphics engine over time form first class and every now and then he asks us to stop using one or the other deprecated features and move on to the newer versions.

Now as part of the current assignment, he asked us to get rid of everything prior to OpenGl ES 2.0. Our codebase is fairly large and I was wondering if I could set OpenGL to 2.0 and above only so that having those deprecated features would actually fail at compile time, so that I can make sure all those features are out of my engine.

Comment: That sounds like a very practical class!

Comment: One of the most practical, useful, well structured and insanely intense classes I ever even heard off...

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your OpenGL context, you can pass hints to the context to request a specific context version. For example, using the [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) library:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(res_width, res_height, window_name, monitor, NULL);
```

This will fail (in the case of GLFW, it returns a `NULL` window) if the OpenGL library doesn't support ES 2.0. Your platform's native EGL (or WGL, GLX, AGL, etc.) functions offer this functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use any libraries except for core openGL. Thanks for the tip though. I will look into it